# Trying to check the Solidity contract for an opcode

Tags: truffle

I want to check the SC for a specific opcode. I am working on truffle console. I found the following code:

```
const { EVM } = require("evm");
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://api.mycryptoapi.com/eth"));

web3.eth.getCode("0x06012c8cf97BEaD5deAe237070F9587f8E7A266d").then(code => {  
    const evm = new EVM(code);
    console.log(evm.getOpcodes());  /* Get opcodes */
});
```

But when I am typing this code I am getting the error on the first line:

```
    $truffle console
    truffle(development)> const { EVM } = require("evm");
    Thrown:
    { internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
        throw err;
        ^

Error: Cannot find module 'evm'
```

Somebody please guide me some other technique or help me to get rid of this error.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

Solution: npm install evm

Zulfi.